# Nested for loop for networkx add nodes

Tags: python, networkx

[image]

I'm using the networkx library to test different algorithms such as prims and kruksal.
I have a data-frame as per the attached picture. The single digits are the nodes and the remaining are the weights. For example, in row 0, 5 is connected to 7 and it has 3 different weights; 5 is connected to 6 and it has 3 different weights.

To add the edges, I have written the following code to calculate one weight:

```
G.add_edge(data1[0][0],data1[1][0],weight=data1[2+i][0])
G.add_edge(data1[0][0],data1[5][0],weight=data1[6+i][0])
G.add_edge(data1[0][0],data1[9][0],weight=data1[10+i][0])
G.add_edge(data1[0][0],data1[13][0],weight=data1[14+i][0])
G.add_edge(data1[0][0],data1[17][0],weight=data1[18+i][0])
G.add_edge(data1[0][0],data1[21][0],weight=data1[22+i][0])
G.add_edge(data1[0][0],data1[0][0],weight=data1[0+i][0])


G.add_edge(data1[0][1],data1[1][1],weight=data1[2+i][1])
G.add_edge(data1[0][1],data1[5][1],weight=data1[6+i][1])
G.add_edge(data1[0][1],data1[9][1],weight=data1[10+i][1])
G.add_edge(data1[0][1],data1[13][1],weight=data1[14+i][1])
G.add_edge(data1[0][1],data1[17][1],weight=data1[18+i][1])
G.add_edge(data1[0][1],data1[21][1],weight=data1[22+i][1])
#G.add_edge(data1[0][1],data1[25][1],weight=data1[26+i][1])


G.add_edge(data1[0][2],data1[1][2],weight=data1[2+i][2])
G.add_edge(data1[0][2],data1[5][2],weight=data1[6+i][2])
G.add_edge(data1[0][2],data1[9][2],weight=data1[10+i][2])
G.add_edge(data1[0][2],data1[13][2],weight=data1[14+i][2])
G.add_edge(data1[0][2],data1[17][2],weight=data1[18+i][2])
G.add_edge(data1[0][2],data1[21][2],weight=data1[22+i][2])
#G.add_edge(data1[0][2],data1[25][2],weight=data1[26+i][2])

G.add_edge(data1[0][3],data1[1][3],weight=data1[2+i][3])
G.add_edge(data1[0][3],data1[5][3],weight=data1[6+i][3])
G.add_edge(data1[0][3],data1[9][3],weight=data1[10+i][3])
G.add_edge(data1[0][3],data1[13][3],weight=data1[14+i][3])
G.add_edge(data1[0][3],data1[17][3],weight=data1[18+i][3])
G.add_edge(data1[0][3],data1[21][2],weight=data1[22+i][3])
#G.add_edge(data1[0][3],data1[25][2],weight=data1[26+i][3])

G.add_edge(data1[0][4],data1[1][4],weight=data1[2+i][4])
G.add_edge(data1[0][4],data1[5][4],weight=data1[6+i][4])
G.add_edge(data1[0][4],data1[9][4],weight=data1[10+i][4])
G.add_edge(data1[0][4],data1[13][4],weight=data1[14+i][4])
G.add_edge(data1[0][4],data1[17][3],weight=data1[18+i][4])
G.add_edge(data1[0][4],data1[21][2],weight=data1[22+i][4])
#G.add_edge(data1[0][4],data1[25][2],weight=data1[26+i][4])

G.add_edge(data1[0][5],data1[1][5],weight=data1[2+i][5])
G.add_edge(data1[0][5],data1[5][5],weight=data1[6+i][5])
G.add_edge(data1[0][5],data1[9][5],weight=data1[10+i][5])
G.add_edge(data1[0][5],data1[13][5],weight=data1[14+i][5])
G.add_edge(data1[0][5],data1[17][5],weight=data1[18+i][5])
G.add_edge(data1[0][5],data1[21][5],weight=data1[22+i][5])
G.add_edge(data1[0][5],data1[25][5],weight=data1[26+i][5])

G.add_edge(data1[0][6],data1[1][6],weight=data1[2+i][6])
G.add_edge(data1[0][6],data1[5][6],weight=data1[6+i][6])
G.add_edge(data1[0][6],data1[9][6],weight=data1[10+i][6])
G.add_edge(data1[0][6],data1[13][6],weight=data1[14+i][6])
G.add_edge(data1[0][6],data1[17][6],weight=data1[18+i][6])
G.add_edge(data1[0][6],data1[21][6],weight=data1[22+i][6])

G.add_edge(data1[0][7],data1[1][7],weight=data1[2+i][7])
G.add_edge(data1[0][7],data1[5][7],weight=data1[6+i][7])
G.add_edge(data1[0][7],data1[9][7],weight=data1[10+i][7])
G.add_edge(data1[0][7],data1[13][7],weight=data1[14+i][7])
G.add_edge(data1[0][7],data1[17][7],weight=data1[18+i][7])
G.add_edge(data1[0][7],data1[21][7],weight=data1[22+i][7])

G.add_edge(data1[0][8],data1[1][8],weight=data1[2+i][8])
G.add_edge(data1[0][8],data1[5][8],weight=data1[6+i][8])
G.add_edge(data1[0][8],data1[9][8],weight=data1[10+i][8])
G.add_edge(data1[0][8],data1[13][8],weight=data1[14+i][8])
G.add_edge(data1[0][8],data1[17][8],weight=data1[18+i][8])
G.add_edge(data1[0][8],data1[21][8],weight=data1[22+i][8])

G.add_edge(data1[0][9],data1[1][9],weigh=data1[2+i][9])
G.add_edge(data1[0][9],data1[5][9],weight=data1[6+i][9])
G.add_edge(data1[0][9],data1[9][9],weight=data1[10+i][9])
G.add_edge(data1[0][9],data1[13][9],weight=data1[14+i][9])
G.add_edge(data1[0][8],data1[17][9],weight=data1[18+i][9])
G.add_edge(data1[0][8],data1[21][9],weight=data1[22+i][9])
```

I'm now looking to automate the above code through a nested for loop. I've written :

```
g = 0
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,9):
        if data1[g+1][0] == None:
            break
        else:
            G.add_edge(data1[0][j],data1[1+g][j],weight=data1[2+i][j])
            g+=4
```

But the above code is giving me an error. Can someone please help?

Comment: would you please let us know what that error is?

Comment: pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 29

Comment: The error means that you're trying to retrieve a value from the dataframe by `loc` and that `loc` doesn't exist. In general, you should rather use [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas.DataFrame.iloc) when you want to index by position and now by a meaningful row/column name. I guess your `g` get out of bounds.